# Extract required libraries into generated Jar with Gradle

Tags: java, jar, gradle

I'm trying to build a (fat) jar with gradle to the likes of what is being generated by eclipse when choosing export->runnable jar and the option *Extract required libraries into generated*.

Eclipse extracts all linked jars into the new jar. In ant this looks like this:

```
<zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="./lib/soot-trunk.jar"/>
```

How can I do the same thing with gradle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to create a fat jar [this](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) plugin is used. You need to invoke a `shadowJar` task.